# My 'almostIncreasingSequence(sequence)' code is too slow for lists that have 10000+ elements. [CodeSignal]

Tags: performance, python-3.x

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66769861/how-is-my-almostincreasingsequencesequence-code-incorrect-codesignal) question on Stackoverflow as well, but I think it's best suited here because my code needs optimization instead of error checking (that I previously thought).

I've made changes to my code as well. But the logic is pretty much the same:

- My code first checks the length of the provided sequence, if it is 2 or less it automatically returns `True`.
- Next, it creates a `newlist` with the first element removed and checks if the rest of the list is in ascending order.
- If the sequence is not in order, the iteration `breaks` and a `newlist` is generated again and this time with the next element removed.
- This continues until there are no more elements to remove (i.e. `i == len(sequence) - 1`), which ultimately returns as `False`
- If in any of the iterations, the list is found to be in ascending order(i.e. `in_order` remains `True`), the function returns `True`.

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    # return True for lists with 2 or less elements.
    if len(sequence) <= 2:
        return True

    # Outerloop, removes i-th element from sequence at each iteration
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        newlist = sequence[:i] + sequence[i+1:]

        # Innerloop, checks if the sequence is in ascending order
        j = 0
        in_order = True
        while j < len(newlist) - 1:
            if newlist[j+1] <= newlist[j]:
                in_order = False
                break
            j += 1
        if in_order == True:
            return True
        elif i == len(sequence)-1:
            return False
```

---

I received a suggestion that **I should only use one loop**, but I cannot think of a way to implement that. Nested loops seems necessary because of the following assumptions:

1. I have to remove every next element from the original sequence. (outer loop)
2. I need to check if all the elements are in order. (inner loop)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017251/solve-almostincreasingsequence-codefights) is a brief on `almostIncreasingSequence()` my code follows the logic provided in the answer here, it solves almost all of the Tests as well, but it is too slow for larger lists (that are approx 10000+ elements).

Comment: Please define "almost".

Comment: Since full sorting is known to be O(N*logN), you have to do at least that good.  Your description sounds like O(N*N).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Checking if a list is strictly increasing

The inner loop checks if a list (in this case `newList`) is strictly increasing:

```py
j = 0
in_order = True
while j < len(newlist) - 1:
    if newlist[j+1] <= newlist[j]:
        in_order = False
        break
    j += 1
if in_order == True:
    return True
```

1. In general variable names should use underscores, so `newlist` becomes `new_list`. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).
2. It can be simplified with a `for-else`:

```py
for j in range(len(new_list) - 1):
    if new_list[j+1] <= new_list[j]:
        break
else:
    return True
```

Or using `all`:

```py
if all(new_list[i] > new_list[i - 1] for i in range(1, len(new_list))):
    return True
```

### Optimization

As you said, the solution is too slow for large input due to the inner loop that runs every time, making the overall complexity \$O(n^2)\$.

The current solution follows this approach:

1. For each element of the input list
2. Build a new list without such element and check if strictly increasing

Consider simplifying the approach like the following:

1. Find the first pair that is not strictly increasing
2. Build a new list without the first element of the pair and check if it is increasing
3. Build a new list without the second element of the pair and check if it is increasing

For example:

```py
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    def is_increasing(l):
        return all(l[i] > l[i - 1] for i in range(1, len(l)))

    if is_increasing(sequence):
        return True

    # Find non-increasing pair
    left, right = 0, 0
    for i in range(len(sequence) - 1):
        if sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]:
            left, right = i, i + 1
            break

    # Remove left element and check if it is strictly increasing
    if is_increasing(sequence[:left] + sequence[right:]):
        return True

    # Remove right element and check if it is strictly increasing
    if is_increasing(sequence[:right] + sequence[right + 1:]):
        return True

    return False
```

I believe there should be an approach that doesn't build the two additional lists to reduce the space complexity, but I'll leave that to you.